# jar file wont run in java 7 but works in java 6

Tags: java, linux, jar

After java update "nothing" happends when i run

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cert.cer -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456 -jar client.jar
```

I get no outputs and the terminal is busy until ctrl+c

If I run it in the old environment it works just fine, eg:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cert.cer -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456 -jar client.jar
```

What might cause issues like this and how do I debug it?

java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Use oracle's jvm instead

Comment: If client.jar is your software, add log statements to find out where it hangs.

Comment: I got lots of log statements. But it does not print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the thread stack dump ...

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0xb6506800 nid=0xfd2 runnable [0xb66de000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(Reflection.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:86)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:66)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:82)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:34)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:360)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:319)
        at se.poject.encoder.Client.<clinit>(Client.java:27)
```

... it looks like there is something strange happening in log4j.  The problem starts in your `Client` class at line 27 (which appears to be a static initialization of some kind).  It appears to be trying to get a `Logger` ... and getting stuck in a "busy" loop of some kind within the log4j implementation.

---

I suspect that this is a bug in Log4j.

- It appears (from the log4j package names) that you are using Log4j 2.0.  This is still in "beta".  You working on the bleeding edge ...
- The line numbers in the stack trace seem to match the source code for beta-5 or beta-6.  The latest version of log4j 2.0 is beta-9.  Try upgrading to the latest beta you can get your hands on.

Answer (score 0):

Is it using any CPU?

To get a thread dump, send it this signal:

kill -3

(The thread dump will be written to stdout).

You could  also try expanding the jar, looking up the main class in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, and specifying the main class explicitly:

java -jar jarname.jar the.main.Class

Comment: Yes, it is using CPU. Much more than when running in java 6.

Comment: I'd get the thread dump, and see what it's up to. You might need to take a few samples to get a clear picture.

Comment: Here it comes: http://textdump.net/read/3374/ . Btw running the main class explicity gives the same results.